# ASP.net Web API: Include validation rules when retrieving models with Data Annotations

Tags: backbone.js, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I'm currently building a Backbone.js/ASP.net MVC/Web API application and everything is going very smooth :)

When sending data to the server I know I can use ModelState and a ValidationFilter to validate there. However, when retrieving a model from the server, I'd like to include any validation rules that come from Data Annotations so that I can hook them into JQuery Validate or whatever I decide on. In ASP.net SPA you can call dataSource.getEntityValidationRules() from javascript to do exactly that.

I was wondering if there was a way to include these rules whenever I get a model with data annotations from Web API without the use of ASP.net SPA and its javascript libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of backbone models is that those are are dynamic, so you can create a parser to read the validations form the server and add those validations to the backbone model in the way your pluggin need it, its kind of easy if you only use: required, minlength, max length and a regex but gets harder with ranges or some other kind of validations.
As I said plug those validation requires a some work to build this parser as I think there is no plugging or library for that.